# How do I add properties to a Web API Response that I do not store in my DB?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a C# Web API using Entity Framework 6.0.  I have the simplest User Class with 3 properties that I persist on SQL into a User Table with 3 corresponding columns where UserID is its the Primary Key.

```
public partial class User
{
    public string UserID {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

I want to add to the Web API two output-only properties on the fly that I do not care to store in my DB.  I use these properties to communicate to the consuming client "Status" and "Message" information that are not part of the User Class.  Status = OK|Error|Warning.  Message would be any message the Web API needs to communicate back to the calling client.

My question is: what is the simplest way to add these two properties on the fly upon sending back the Web API's response WITHOUT modifying the underlying User Table on SQL?  I know I can add these two as dummy columns to the User Table.  I don't want to carry around that overhead on the SQL side when I don't need it there.

Comment: Do not return the ef object as a web api response. Map properties to some DTO class and return it instead. This DTO should contain properties from User class and additional data you want.

Comment: Thank you emre.  Can you please add an example?  See the answers and my responses below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with more generic approach:

```
public class MyResponse<T>
{
    public T Data {get;set;}
    public Status ResponseStatus{get;set;}
    public string Message{get;set;}
}
```

This way you can handle all you models/data in the same way.

**UPDATE**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[RoutePrefix("api/home")]
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ok")]
    public MyResponse<MyUser> OK()
    {
        MyUser m = new MyUser();
        var r = MyResponse<MyUser>.Success(m);
        return r;
    }

    [Route("nok")]
    [HttpGet]
    public MyResponse<MyUser> NOK()
    {
        var r = MyResponse<MyUser>.Error("something went terribly wrong");
        return r;
    }
}

public class MyResponse<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Status ResponseStatus { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }

    private MyResponse() { }

    public static MyResponse<T> Success(T data)
    {
        return new MyResponse<T> { Data = data, ResponseStatus = Status.Success };
    }

    public static MyResponse<T> Error(string message)
    {
        return new MyResponse<T> { ResponseStatus = Status.Error, Message = message };
    }
}

public class MyUser
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public enum Status
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Success = 1,
    Error
}
```

Comment: this is very close to what I am looking for.  Can you please add to your solution how you call your code to pass on the User object and return it to the Web API Response?  Thank you.

Comment: How's this? I pasted slightly changed Generic response.

Comment: Awesome.  What an elegant solution.  Thank you so much, @jstadnicki.  I definitely learnt a lot from your example.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should create a data transfer object (DTO) class in model with all the properties you require, then use a mapper to map your user to the DTO

```
public class UserDto{
   public string UserID {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}

   public string Message {get; set;}
   public string Status {get; set;}
}
```

Then in your action

```
[ResponseType(typeof(UserDto))]
public IHttpActionResult User(string userId){

   // retrive user from db

   var userDto = Mapper.Map<UserDto>(dbUser);

   if(condition){
      userDto.Message = "the message";
      userDto.Status = "the status";
   }

   return Ok(userDto);
}
```

Then you can install Automapper to from nuget and configure it to do the mapping for you.

Comment: Thank you, Ebimie.  That is very close to what I am looking for.  My User Class is much bigger than that.  I don't want to maintain its schema twice.  Can you please expand your code to map the User Class as is without hand coding its schema.  I don't know how to use Automapper.